# item will not remove from cart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Instead of using the product ID, I have an index for each item in the cart starting at 0. Each item in the cart has it's own remove/delete from cart button . When that button is clicked, the value is posted via ajax to a php script:

```
if(isset($_POST['indexToRemove']) && $_POST['indexToRemove'] !== "") {

        $key_to_remove = $_POST['indexToRemove'];
        if(count($_SESSION['cart_array']) <=1) {
            unset($_SESSION['cart_array']);

        } else {

            unset($_SESSION['cart_array'][$key_to_remove]);

        }
    }
```

If I console.log() indexToRemove on click, it shows the correct value in console. But, the item is never removed from the session and there is no error in console to help with troubleshooting.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("body").on("click", ".removeItem", function () {
        var indexToRemove = $(this).data('itr');
        var div = $(this).parents("div.hr");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'functions/show-cart.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                indexToRemove: indexToRemove
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $(div).html("<img src='images/spinner.gif'>");
                $("#total").empty();
            },
        })

        .done(function (data) {
            $(div).fadeOut();
            show_cart();
        })

        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            console.warn(jqXHR.responseText);
        })
    })
```

Add to cart code:

```
$quantity = 1;
$product_id = $_POST['id'];
$colour = $_POST['colour'];
$size = $_POST['size'];


   $key = "{$product_id}.{$colour}.{$size}";
   if (empty($_SESSION['cart_array'][$key])) {
     $_SESSION['cart_array'][$key] = array(
        "item_id" => $product_id,
        "quantity" => $quantity,
        "colour" => $colour,
        "size" => $size,
     );
   }
   else {
      $_SESSION['cart_array'][$key]['quantity'] += $quantity;
   }
```

php code for showing the cart items:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart_array'])) {

    $itemsInCart = 0;
    $response['total'] = 0;
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {

        $featured = "Yes";
        $i=0;
        foreach($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item) {
            $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
            $colour = $each_item['colour'];
            $size = $each_item['size'];


        $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT `product_name`, `price`, `pic_name` FROM `products` as `p` INNER JOIN `product_images` as `pi` ON p.`id` = pi.`product_id` WHERE p.`id` = ? AND `featured` = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("is", $item_id, $featured);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();
            $numRows = $result->num_rows;
            if($numRows > 0) {
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $product_name = sanitize($row['product_name']);
                    $price = sanitize(money_format('%.2n', $row['price']));
                    $subtotal = money_format('%.2n', $each_item['quantity'] * $price);
                    $pic_name = $row['pic_name'];
                    $cartTotal = $subtotal + $cartTotal;
                    $quantity = $each_item['quantity'];

                    $cart_details[] = array(

                    "product_name" => $product_name,
                    "price" => $price,
                    "subtotal" => $subtotal,
                    "pic_name" => $pic_name,
                    "each_item" => $quantity,
                    "item_id" =>$item_id,
                    "i" => $i,
                    "colour" => $colour,
                    "size" => $size,


                    );

                    $i++;
                }
            }

            $stmt->close();
        }


    $response['total'] = $cartTotal;
    $response['cart'] = $cart_details;
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your client side you need to change this line:

```
data: {
     indexToRemove: indexToRemove
 },
```

to:

```
data: JSON.stringify({indexToRemove: indexToRemove}),
```

Instead on server side the first issue is:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart_array']["$key_to_remove"]);
                              ^              ^
```

change it to:

```
unset($_SESSION['cart_array'][$key_to_remove]);
```

The second is (because the item is a json object you need [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)):

```
$key_to_remove = $_POST['indexToRemove'];
```

change it to:

```
$key_to_remove = json_decode($_POST['indexToRemove']);
```

Comment: If I only have 1 item then it works and the item is removed

Comment: I don't know how to check what you are asking. If I console.log() out the indexToRemove, the first cart item has value of 0, seance item value of 1, third item value of 2 and so on

Comment: @user8463989 Sorry, can you dump in PHP the value of your $key_to_remove, and the same for your array and test if the key is valid?  The reason is because I saw **$key = "{$product_id}.{$colour}.{$size}";** and I assume this is not a number.

Comment: @user8463989 Did you consider to use array_push and array_search in order  to insert a new element into the array and getting the value instead to create an index like you do?